# My script only updates the text once

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make a Breakout game in Unity. I made  a lot of the functions work except the "count" function. I want the "count"function to tell the user how many bricks are left. Every time a brick (gameObject) gets destroyed, the int variable "bricks" will decrease by one. The problem I have is that it only updates once (from 104 to 103) then stops updating. Here is my script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour {

public int bricks = 104;
public Text triggerText;

void Start(){
    triggerText.text = "Bricks: "+bricks;
    }

public void OnCollisionEnter(){

    DestroyBrick ();

}

public void DestroyBrick(){
    bricks--;
    Destroy (gameObject);
    triggerText.text = "Bricks: "+bricks;
    }
```

edit: I forgot to mention that I added this script to my Brick gameObjects (104 of them) in order for them to break when collided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have one spawner instance in your scene. When `DestroyBrick` is called you kill this instance by calling `Destroy (gameObject);`. So you stick at *103*.

Possible solutions:

- Remove the call to Destroy if it's one spawner for your 104 bricks
- If it is rather a brick component attached to each spawned Brick instance, either

  - delegate counting to another object let's say BrickCounter
  - make member variable `bricks` static

---

**EDIT** (inspired by @BradleyDotNET's comment):
Static member is OK for testing. But I would always prefer creating a separate class which is responsible for holding the brick count.

Comment: Thank you so much! I understood the problem and making the variable a static fixed my problem! If you dont mind, could you answer me how this fixed the problem? The spawner would still get destroyed. Anyway, thank you very much!

Comment: @tomSurge `static` variables exist once for all instances of the class. They are effectively "global". Using them is... relatively bad practice, unless you know what you are doing. Be careful with them.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I totally agree with you and added a hint to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since *each instance* of the brick game objects has a *unique* instance of this behavior, you get this:

1. Brick 1 starts with count 104
2. Brick 2 starts with count 104
3. Brick 1 is destroyed, its count goes to 103
4. The text is set to 103 by Brick 1
5. Brick 2 is destroyed, **its** count goes to 103
6. The text is set to 103 by Brick 2

Giving the appearance that the count only decrements once. To fix this, you need a *global* script (assigned to a single gameObject) that manages the count. When a brick is destroyed, its behavior should find (or be passed) this behavior instance and invoke a method on it:

```
public void BrickDestroyed()
{
    bricks--;
    triggerText.text = "Bricks: "+bricks;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this block of code is on each of your 104 game objects, then every time this occurs, an integer named 'bricks' is created with a value of 104.

Declare this variable somewhere publicly accessible outside of all of these objects, and only decrement and update text on the brick objects.